# O que é uma Thread? Como ela funciona?

Tags: java, thread

Fiquei confuso a respeito do que uma `thread` é e o que ela representa. Encontrei a seguinte definição para a mesma:

> **Thread** é um pequeno programa que trabalha como um subsistema, sendo
>   uma forma de um processo se autodividir em duas ou mais tarefas. É o
>   termo em inglês para *Linha ou Encadeamento de Execução*. Essas tarefas
>   múltiplas podem ser executadas simultaneamente para rodar mais rápido
>   do que um programa em um único bloco ou praticamente juntas, mas que
>   são tão rápidas que parecem estar trabalhando em conjunto ao mesmo
>   tempo.
>
> *Matéria completa:
>   http://canaltech.com.br/o-que-e/o-que-e/o-que-e-thread/#ixzz3pu7fmDGh 
>   O conteúdo do Canaltech é protegido sob a licença Creative Commons (CC
>   BY-NC-ND). Você pode reproduzi-lo, desde que insira créditos COM O
>   LINK para o conteúdo original e não faça uso comercial de nossa
>   produção.*

Entretanto, ainda não consegui compreende-la. Como funciona uma `thread`? Se possível, alguém poderia elucidar um exemplo prático em `Java` sobre?

Comment: Um dos resultados de https://www.bing.com/search?q=o+que+é+um+thread tem uma boa explicação: http://www.macoratti.net/10/09/c_thd1.htm. Ele fala sobre C#, mas os conceitos são os mesmos para Java.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Pense numa *thread* como uma sequência de comandos sendo executados em um programa. Se você tiver duas *threads*, terá duas sequências de comandos executando ao mesmo tempo **no mesmo programa** ou processo.

Note que executar o mesmo programa duas vezes não é criar mais *threads* e sim criar dois processos do mesmo programa. *Threads* rodam concorrentemente num mesmo processo. Processos executam concorrentemente num sistema operacional.

O uso de *threads* começa a ficar interessante quando você quer executar pelo menos duas coisas ao mesmo tempo em um programa para tirar vantagem da múltiplas CPUs ou ainda para evitar que o programa inteiro fique travado ao executar uma operação demorada.

O caso de uso mais comum de *threads* no Java é para atender requisições em aplicações web. Se você está de alguma forma familiarizado com Servlets, Spring MVC, JSF, Struts ou algum outro framework web Java, deve saber que todos eles atendem cada requisição HTTP em uma *thread* diferente. Isso permite atender vários usuários simultaneamente e ao mesmo tempo ter um certo isolamento das informações, pois o servidor de aplicação (como o Tomcat ou JBoss) associa os dados de cada requisição com a respectiva *thread*, então isso faz com que o mesmo código seja executado por todos os usuários, mas cada com com informações isoladas umas das outras.

Veja uma ilustração do processo ([fonte](http://www.oracle.com/au/products/database/asynchronous-servlets-088344.html)):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 19):

`Threads` em Java (a classe `java.lang.Thread`) são abstrações de *threads* do sistema operacional.

### No sistema operacional

Uma (ou um) *thread* é uma sequência de comandos sendo executada em um programa ou processo. Se você tem duas *threads*, terá duas sequências de comandos rodando em paralelo no mesmo processo.

As *threads* de um processo compartilham o chamado *contexto de execução*, que trocando em miúdos significa que têm todas a mesma visão da memória ocupada pelo processo. Com isso, as variáveis e funções de uma *thread* podem ser acessadas também pelas outras *threads*.

A memória de um processo não é compartilhada por outros processos, então é mais difícil fazer dois processos conversarem. Com threads isso fica mais simples. Processos só são capazes de compartilhar informações de maneira indireta (através de *sockets* ou *pipes*, por exemplo).

Por que os sistemas operacionais modernos permitem programar em *threads* além de processos? Porque além de tornar mais simples a programação multitarefas, é mais eficiente (pois o escalonador está o tempo todo trocando de contexto de execução e essa troca tem um custo, que é menor de uma *thread* para outra do que de um processo para outro, já que o contexto de memória é o mesmo).

Uma última coisa sobre *threads*: um processo normalmente inicia rodando uma única *thread*, que é capaz de se subdividir em uma segunda *thread*, e assim por diante para criar novas *threads* (uma *thread* nascendo da divisão de uma já existente).

### No Java

Uma `Thread` no Java (um objeto da classe `java.lang.Thread`) permite ao seu aplicativo Java rodar uma sequência de instruções em uma *thread* da máquina virtual, que na prática é executada por uma *thread* do sistema operacional hospedeiro ou *kernel thread* (lembrando que a máquina virtual do Java roda em cima de um sistema operacional hospedeiro).

Essas sequências de instruções são encapsuladas dentro de um método `run()` que é passado para o construtor da `Thread` (não o método diretamente, mas um objeto `Runnable`, isto é, que implementa a interface `Runnable` e que portanto implementa o método `run()`). Ou, alternativamente, uma vez que a própria classe `Thread` já implementa `Runnable`, você pode optar por simplesmente implementar esse método no próprio objeto da classe `Thread`.

Porém, somente dar um método `run()` à `Thread` não a faz rodar em paralelo a outras *threads*. É necessário iniciá-la chamando o método `Thread.start()`.

### Exemplo

Aqui duas *threads* competem entre si para mudar o valor de uma variável. Uma incrementa o valor da variável e a outra decrementa o valor. Eventualmente o valor será decrementado porque a segunda *thread* roda mais rápido que a primeira (seus intervalos de sono são mais curtos).

Note também que se você descomentar o `println()` comentado do método `dormir()`, verá que o mesmo trecho de código (o método `dormir()`) está sendo chamado por duas *threads* diferentes.

```
public class TesteComThreads {

    public int variavelCompartilhada = 0;

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        new TesteComThreads().executar();

    }

    public void executar() {
        Thread segundoThread = new ThreadQueDecrementaValorDaVariavel(this);
        segundoThread.start();

        while(true) {
            variavelCompartilhada++;
            System.out.println("Variável vale: " + variavelCompartilhada);
            dormir(1500);
        }
         
    }

    public void dormir(int milissegundos) {
        try {
            // System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " irá dormir por " + milissegundos + " milissegundos.");
            Thread.sleep(milissegundos);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Não precisa fazer nada
        }
    }
}

class ThreadQueDecrementaValorDaVariavel extends Thread {

    private TesteComThreads teste;

    public ThreadQueDecrementaValorDaVariavel(TesteComThreads teste) {
        this.teste = teste;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            teste.variavelCompartilhada--;
            System.out.println("Variável vale: " + teste.variavelCompartilhada);
            teste.dormir(1000);
        }
    }
}
```