# JavaScript - Thread, Assincronismo, Ticks

Tags: javascript, thread, assincronismo

#### Situação

Estudando sobre [`Thread`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95233/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-thread-como-ela-funciona), compreendi que são linhas de execução dentro de um processo.
Estudando sobre [`Assincronismo em javascript`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16950/como-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-funciona-em-javascript), compreendi que ele não tem suporte a múltiplas `Thread`, mas possui um `loop de eventos`.
Fazendo uma analogia com C, seria uma memoria com endereços, que executado sequencialmente cada endereço, assim ao definir um `setTimeout({function}, {time})`, seria o mesmo que setar *{function}* no endereço *{time}* para ser executado.

Contudo como disse o @bfavaretto em sua [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16950/como-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-funciona-em-javascript#answer-16960), não quer disser que vai executar no *{time}*, mas no próximo momento que o `loop de eventos` esteja livre.

#### Teste

```
(function(){
    var start = null;

    var checkTicks = function(){
        start = new Date();         // SETA start COM DATA CORRENTE
        var s = start.getSplitDate();
        start = new Date(s['year'],s['month'],s['day'],s['hours'],s['minutes'],s['seconds']);

        setTimeout(showDiff, 1000); // DEFINE FUNÇÃO A SER EXECUTADA APOS 1s
        loop();                     // CHAMADO DE LOOP QUE DEVE DEMORAR 5s
    }

    var loop = function(){
        var stop = false;
        while(!stop){
            var current = new Date();
            var s = current.getSplitDate();
            current = new Date(s['year'], s['month'], s['day'], s['hours'], s['minutes'], s['seconds']);

            if(betweenDates(current.toTimestamp(), start.toTimestamp(), 's') > 5){ // SO PARA APOS DIFF DE 5s
                stop = true;
            }
        }
    }

    var showDiff = function(){
        var current = new Date();
        var s = current.getSplitDate();
        current = new Date(s['year'],s['month'],s['day'],s['hours'],s['minutes'],s['seconds']);

        console.log(start.toTimestamp());
        console.log(current.toTimestamp());

        console.log(betweenDates(current.toTimestamp(), start.toTimestamp(), 's')); // EXIBE DIFERENCA ENTRE start E current
    }

    checkTicks(); // INICIO O PROCESSO
})();
```

#### Resultado do console

6

#### Duvida

- Por que o resultado foi **6** tendo em vista que o comando `setTimeout(showDiff, 1000);` definiu `showDiff` a ser executado em 1s?
- O `loop de eventos` ficou ocupado por 5s, `showDiff` não deveria ser executado imediatamente apos?

#### Edição

Conversando com o @bfavaretto novamente a lógica tinha algumas inconsistências pois não levada em consideração os milissegundos do objeto Date, para resolver isso setei duas vezes o a variável, no segundo sem os milissegundos, passando apenas os valores relevantes.

#### Auxiliar

#### betweenDates

```js
 function betweenDates(d1, d2, diff, returnLiteral){
 
  d1   = d1.split(' '); // Divide o timestamp em data e hora
  d1[0] = d1[0].split('-'); // Separa as variacoes da data
  d1[1] = d1[1].split(':'); // Separa as variacoes da hora
  d1  = d1[0].concat(d1[1]); // concatena os dois conteudos formando um array unico.
 
  d1 = new Date(d1[0],d1[1],d1[2],d1[3],d1[4],d1[5]); // gera o objeto date
  d1 = Date.UTC(d1.getFullYear(), d1.getMonth(), d1.getDate(), d1.getHours(), d1.getMinutes(), d1.getSeconds()); // retona o time UTC corespondente da data.
  
  d2   = d2.split(' ');
  d2[0] = d2[0].split('-');
  d2[1] = d2[1].split(':');
  d2  = d2[0].concat(d2[1]);
 
  d2 = new Date(d2[0],d2[1],d2[2],d2[3],d2[4],d2[5]);
  d2 = Date.UTC(d2.getFullYear(), d2.getMonth(), d2.getDate(), d2.getHours(), d2.getMinutes(), d2.getSeconds());
  
  var dDiff = d2 - d1; // calcula a diferenca entre as datas
  
  var out = {
   'y' : dDiff/1000/60/60/24/30/12, // calculo para ano
   'm' : dDiff/1000/60/60/24/30,  // calculo para mes
   'd' : dDiff/1000/60/60/24,   // calculo para dia
   'h' : dDiff/1000/60/60,    // calculo para hora
   'i' : dDiff/1000/60,    // calculo para minuto
   's' : dDiff/1000/1     // calculo para segundo
  };
 
  out = Math.floor(out[diff]); // Saida (inteiro do calculo)
  
  // Retorno
  if(out < 0 && !returnLiteral){
   return out*-1;
  }else{
   return out;
  }
 }
```

#### Date.prototype.getSplitDate

```js
 Date.prototype.getSplitDate = function(){
  var day  = this.getDate();
  var month = this.getMonth();
  var year = this.getFullYear();
 
  var hours = this.getHours();
  var minutes = this.getMinutes();
  var seconds = this.getSeconds();
 
  var o = {};
  o['day'] = day;
  o['month'] = month;
  o['year'] = year;
 
  o['hours'] = hours;
  o['minutes']= minutes;
  o['seconds']= seconds;
 
  return o;
 }
```

#### Date.prototype.toTimestamp

```js
 Date.prototype.toTimestamp = function(short){
 
  var o = this.getSplitDate();
 
  var date = '####-##-## ##:##:##';
 
  date = o['year'].toString().lpad(0,4).mask(date);
  date = o['month'].toString().lpad(0,2).mask(date);
  date = o['day'].toString().lpad(0,2).mask(date);
 
  date = o['hours'].toString().lpad(0,2).mask(date);
  date = o['minutes'].toString().lpad(0,2).mask(date);
  date = o['seconds'].toString().lpad(0,2).mask(date);
 
  if(short){
   date = date.split(' ');
   return date[0];
  }else{
   return date;
  }
 }
```

#### String.prototype.mask

```js
 String.prototype.mask = function(mask){
  var value = onlyNumber(this);
 
  for(var i = 0; i <= mask.substrCount('#'); i++){
 
   if(typeof(value[i]) === 'undefined'){
    break;
   } 
 
   var k = mask.indexOf('#');
   mask = mask.split('');
   mask[k] = value[i];
   mask = mask.join('');
  }
 
  return mask;
 }
```

Comment: @bfavaretto, se possível gostaria de sua analise.

Comment: O que tem aqui: betweenDates. Poderia colocar o conteudo desse método também?

Comment: @EmirMarques é um método grande, creio não ter relevância para esta questão, o que ele faz é basicamente compara duas `string` em formato `timestamp` e pegar a diferença em segundos. Mas se deseja ver o método, pois talvez lhe interesse, eu monto uma pergunta sobre e ponho como resposta.

Comment: Pode ser o arredondamento do `betweenDates`, não? Talvez tenha dado `5.x`.

Comment: @bfavaretto realmente tem um `Math.floor`, mas como é segundo acaba se tornando inteiro, de qualquer modo. Editei , colocando a função

Comment: O que é `.toTimestamp()`?

Comment: E quando usas `betweenDates(current.toTimestamp(), start.toTimestamp(), 's')` o argumento `diff`  dentro da função `betweenDates` vai ser uma string... é isso que queres?

Comment: @Sergio acho que agora tem todas as funções envolvida, quanto ao diff, sim uma string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que a melhor forma de esclarecer esse problema é ressaltar a diferença entre **concorrência** e **paralelismo** e a diferença entre concorrência **cooperativa** e **preemptiva**.

Na computação paralela você tem várias coisas executando ao mesmo tempo (literalmente, em múltiplos processadores) mas não necessariamente essas computações vão interagir uma com a outra.

Se você estiver fazendo computações concorrentes, tem mais de uma "linha de execução" sendo executada em um dado momento mas pode ser que elas estejam rodando em um único processador. A linha de execução A roda um pouco, depois ela pausa e a linha B roda um pouco, e por assim vai.

Finalmente, numa situação em que você tem várias linhas de execução compartilhando um processador, pode ser que esse compartilhamento seja cooperativo ou preemptivo.

- Numa situação **cooperativa** as linhas de execução abrem mão do processador explicitamente. Em Javascript isso ocorre toda vez que você faz uma chamada de sistema assíncrona, que devolve o controle pro loop de eventos.
- Por outro lado, numa situação com concorrência **preemptiva** o sistema pode interromper a execução a qualquer momento. É isso que ocorre com os processos do seu sistema operacional ou nas threads tradicionais que você já conhece.

---

Voltando ao seu problema, o que ocorreu é que a função `loop` nunca devolve o controle para o loop de eventos. É um while simples e esse while vai continuar rodando até que a condição de parada fique falsa. No fim das contas você meio que implementou uma [spin lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock).

Uma maneira de resolver esse problema é botar um timeout entre cada iteração do loop.

```
function meuloop(){
    var current = new Date();
    if(betweenDates(current.toTimestamp(), start.toTimestamp(), 's') < 5){
        // Peça para o loop de eventos continuar o  "meu loop" assim que puder.
        // Dessa forma, o loop de eventos tem a oportunidade de
        // rodar outros eventos também.
        setTimeout(meuloop, 0);
    }else{
        console.log("acabou");
    }
}
```

BTW, no node você também pode usar a função [nextTick](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_arg) ao invés de um timeout com zero:

```
proccess.nextTick(meuloop)
```

Comment: Cara achei bem interessante os termos e irei estudar mais sobre, assim com fazer os devidos testes. Só que agora estou sem tempo. Obrigado a ajuda.

Comment: De fato o problema é que eu não devolvia o controle para o `loop de eventos`.

Comment: Então, no JavaScript, nada é executado paralelamente, mas sim, alternadamente?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam: Sim. E além disso a concorrência é cooperativa e não preemptiva.

Comment: Tem algum exemplo de linguagem que use concorrência preemptiva?

Comment: Threads geralmente usam concorrência preemptiva. Por exemplo, pthreads em C e threads de Java.

Answer (score 5):

A sua função `betweenDates` é muito imprecisa, ela nunca usa a informação de milissegundos que os objetos do tipo `Date` incluem. Fiz um teste alterando um pouco o seu código, e o resultado foi `5.007` segundos:

```
(function(){
    var start = null;

    var checkTicks = function(){
        start = new Date();         // SETA start COM DATA CORRENTE
        setTimeout(showDiff, 1000); // DEFINE FUNÇÃO A SER EXECUTADA APOS 1s
        loop();                     // CHAMADO DE LOOP QUE DEVE DEMORAR 5s
    }

    var loop = function(){
        var stop = false;
        while(!stop){
            var current = new Date();
            if(betweenDates(current, start) > 5){ // SO PARA APOS DIFF DE 5s
                stop = true;
            }
        }
    }

    var showDiff = function(){
        var current = new Date();
        console.log(betweenDates(current, start)); // EXIBE DIFERENCA ENTRE start E current
    }

    checkTicks(); // INICIO O PROCESSO
})();

function betweenDates(d1, d2) {
    return (d1.getTime() - d2.getTime()) / 1000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vux13w4k/

Comment: Quando eu montei `betweenDate`, me baseei [nesta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript), quanto a questão dos milissegundos, eu sei que o javascript trabalha com base neles, mas não é estranho que tenha um diferença de `0.07`, para dados sólidos? se nenhuma das datas tem milissegundos como se pode haver essa diferença? seria algo relacionado a [isto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript#comment-1306826)?

Comment: No meu exemplo, as datas incluem sim os milissegundos. Não entendi bem o que ainda não ficou claro pra você...

Comment: Sim ia mesmo comentar agora

Comment: ainda estou fazendo testes aqui, mas assim não vai incluir milissegudos `start = new Date();  var s = start.getSplitDate(); start = new Date(s['year'], s['month'], s['day'], s['hours'], s['minutes'], s['seconds']);`

Comment: `new Date().getTime()` inclui os milissegundos (que fazem parte do valor interno guardado no objeto Date).

Comment: Editei a pergunta, agora não vai mais incluir os milissegundos : D

Comment: Eu achei que você não tinha entendido o porquê dos 6 segundos, não do seu timeout esperar até o fim do loop para executar...