# Como liberar thread congelado/travado?

Tags: javascript, thread

#### Estudando sobre JS:

- [JavaScript - Thread, Assincronismo, Ticks](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97840/javascript-thread-assincronismo-ticks)
- [Como programação assíncrona funciona em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16950/como-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-funciona-em-javascript)

> Só existe uma thread para executar seu código, é preciso evitar ao máximo que esse código bloqueie a thread. [(bfavaretto♦)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16950/como-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-funciona-em-javascript#answer-16960)

#### Situação

Não são raras as vezes em que acabamos travando a thread :

```
var error = function(){
    console.log("Error!!!");
}

window.onerror = error;

t.add(); // ReferenceError: t is not defined; Error!!!;
```

#### Duvida

Após a `thread` travar tem como destrava-la? utilizando a função `error`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não existe bem como *destravar*, o seu script é um caso de loop infinito e não tem como parar sem finalizar o processo todo, pois o javascript roda em um evento único e o que provavelmente congelou foi o processo e não só a Thread, em alguma perguntas comentei sobre algo semelhante:

- [Qual a vantagem real de usar um CallBack e o que é thread/multithread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635)
- [Por que as vezes é necessário o setTimeout com valor 0 (zero)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94853/3635)

A técnica citada com `setTimeout` por exemplo ajudam apenas a minimizar o problema (no caso do teu script é mais um erro do que um problema `:)` ), mas nestas duas respostas também citei:

- [AMD Asynchronous module definition](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html)
- [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage)

Que são possiveis soluções para o que deseja alcançar. o jQuery por exemplo usa o [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html), veja esta é uma parte do jquery:

```
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
    define( "jquery", [], function() {
        return jQuery;
    });
}
```

No entanto o que mais provavelmente vai lhe ajudar é o [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage) que conforme a documentação roda realmente em uma Thread separada do navegador:

> Web Workers provide a simple means for web content to run scripts in background threads. The worker thread can perform tasks without interfering with the user interface
>
> **Traduzindo:** O Web Workers proporcionar um meio simples para conteúdo da Web para executar scripts para rodar scripts em Thread no background. O `worker thread` pode rodar tarefas sem interferir na interface do usuário.

### Exemplo com web workers

Para criar um processo com *web works* é necessário criar um arquivo .js (vamos chama-lo de `meujavascript.js`) separado e chama-lo assim:

```
var meuWorker = new Worker("meujavascript.js");
```

Pra capturar as respostas do script `meujavascript.js`, você terá que usar `onmessage`:

```
meuWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
   console.log('Mensagem recebida do Worker', e.data);
};
```

Para enviar dados ao `meuWorker.onmessage` no conteúdo do `meujavascript.js` você deve usar:

```
postMessage("mensagem");
```

Você também pode enviar dados ao `meujavascript.js` assim:

```
var worker = new Worker("meujavascript.js");
worker.postMessage('Olá mundo!');
```

E no conteudo do `meujavascript.js` você deve adicionar algo como:

```
onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('Mensagem recebida do MAIN', e.data);
};
postMessage("mensagem");
```

**Agora vem a resposta**, você pode "terminar" (matar, kill, etc) um webworker, usando `terminate()`, desta maneira:

```
var worker = new Worker("meujavascript.js");
worker.postMessage('Olá mundo!');
worker.terminate();
```

Então você pode trabalhar com um `setTimeout` no `main` (fora do worker) e verificar se faz muito tempo que o webworker não envia mensagem, provavelmente houve um congelamento, então se o tempo do `setTimeout` expirar você executa o `terminate`.

Comment: Passar uma tarefa para o web worker pode melhorar a performance ou apenas vai estar dividindo a capacidade de processamento, podendo diminuir a performance?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam passe a tarefa para o worker se isso for necessário, independente de performance, que por sinal será relativa e vai variar muito de como funciona o seu código especifico e não do Worker ou do processo principal.