# document.writeln() está em desuso javascript

Tags: javascript

Quando `document.writeln()` usado para mostrar texto no html está em desuso? Alguém conhece outra forma de mostra uma string na tela?

Segue o xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">     
<head> 
    <title> JavaScript Objeto String</title>    

    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/ObjetoString.js"> </script> 

</head>    
<body>    

</body>
</html>
```

Segue o javascript

```
var x = new String("Texto dentro de aspas é string");

document.writeln();
```

Error na saida

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

Comment: você quer adicionar um conteúdo sem apagar a página, é isso?

Comment: Não, quero mostra o valor da string "x" na tela apenas isso. Mas ta aparecendo o error acima, q diz que nao está mais em uso ..

Comment: qual navegador vc está usando? No firefox funcionou sem problema.

Comment: No meu nao funciona estou usando Firefox com o Firebug

Comment: vou deixar uma resposta abaixo, tente executar o código

Comment: cass persiste o problema, substitua `new String` por apenas `"adsad"`

Comment: oloko,serio isso, nao deu certo ..

Comment: Inventar uma interpretação nova pra mensagem de erro não vai ajudar em nada. Provavelmente tem algum erro básico de sintaxe no seu código, e o erro que está tendo é um efeito colateral. Além disso, melhor não inventar moda e fazer `var x = "String é um texto dentro de aspas ";`, se estiver fazendo uma aplicação convencional.

Comment: Testei seu código no Firefox e nenhum erro ocorreu o problema deve ser em outro script, veja minha resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/121928/3635

Answer (score 4):

Não o `document.write` ou `document.writeln` não estão em desuso, eu testei o script e ele não faz nada e também não apresenta erro algum. Então fiz assim:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript Objeto String</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="arquivo.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>test</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

arquivo.js:

```
var x = new String("Texto dentro de aspas é string");
document.writeln(x);
```

Apenas no IE11 aparece um erro:

> HTML1514: Extra "<body>" tag found. Only one "<body>" tag should exist per document.

Mas esse erro não é de Javascript e sim de HTML, quando usa `document.write` antes do body sem uma tag valida para `<head>` o IE automaticamente cria o `<BODY>`, mas logo em seguida ele encontra outro `<body>` (definido por você) e isso causa um conflito (irei explicar como evitar).

Provavelmente o erro:

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

É ocasionado por outro script e você fez alguma confusão (vou falar do erro `InvalidStateError` a seguir).

### O que são `document.write` e `document.writeln`

O `document.write` é usado pra "escrever" no documento, mas não pra manipular o DOM "dinamicamente" e nem de maneira assíncrona, isso quer dizer que se você executar `document.write` dentro de `<head>` assim:

```
<head>
<script>
document.write("Teste");
</script>
</head>
```

Seria o mesmo que escrever isso:

```
<head>
Teste
</head>
```

Ou seja isso não vai inserir dentro do BODY (aonde provavelmente é o seu objetivo), você só deve usar `document.write` em `head` se pretende inserir uma tag valida pra `<head>`, por exemplo digamos que você quer inserir um javascript sem e prevenir o cache dele, você pode fazer assim:

```
<head>
<script>
var time = new Date().getTime();
document.write('<script src="file.js?_=' + time + '"></script>');
</script>
</head>
```

Ou então quer mostrar a data no título:

```
<head>
<script>
var minhaData = new Date();
document.write('<title>' + minhaData + '</title>');
</script>
</head>
```

> São apenas exemplos e não que realmente você deve usar

O que importa é entender que dentro de `<head>` só pode haver tags validas, mesmo que o conteúdo seja inserido por `document.write`.

O `document.writeln` é quase idêntico ao `document.write`, a unica diferença é que ele gera uma quebra de linha no final da string inserida, seria quase o mesmo que:

```
document.write("Foo bar\n");
```

### `document.write` em eventos

O `document.write` se usado em eventos como `click` ou `onload` não irá adicionar apenas conteudo, ele irá sobrescrever o `<body></body>` existente, por exemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("testar").onclick = function() {
    document.write("Olá mundo!");
};
```

```html
<p>test</p>

<button id="testar">Testar</button>
```

O `document.write` fora de eventos e antes do documento ser processado não sobrescreve apenas insere, mas depois de processado ele necessita reconstruir a estrutura e pra isso precisa limpar primeiro todo `<body>`, raramente você vai usar algo desta maneira (como no exemplo acima).

### Como inserir conteúdo na página dinamicamente

Pra evitar limpar o body você tem várias opções, como `.innerHTML`, `.appendChild`, `.insertBefore`

Um exemplo com `innerHTML`:

```js
var conteudo = document.getElementById("conteudo");

document.getElementById("testar").onclick = function() {
    conteudo.innerHTML = "Olá mundo! Data atual: " + (new Date());
};
```

```html
<p>test</p>

<div id="conteudo"></div>

<button id="testar">Testar</button>
```

### O erro InvalidStateError

Aparentemente esse problema ocorre em requisições Ajax, ou em certas manipulações DOM o qual o objeto "mudou" ou não existe, a situação é bem variante, mas um exemplo que o problema ocorre é quando tentamos setar um header no `XMLHttpRequest` antes do `.open`, isso apresenta o erro:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest' );
```

Pra corrigir faça isto:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'pagina.html', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest' );
```

Recomendo que estude e aprenda como funciona eventos/callbacks, recomendo estas duas respostas:

- [Como liberar thread congelado/travado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100657/3635)
- [Qual a vantagem real de usar um CallBack e o que é thread/multithread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635)

### XHTML e HTML5

Notei que o seu código usa XHTML, eu não vejo necessidade disso em páginas padrões ou básicas, a não ser que você vá trabalhar com alguma estrutura de XML dentro da estrutura do HTML, todavia recomendo começar a usar HTML5, ou se quiser ainda sim continuar usando o DTD STRICT então use o HTML4.01, na maior parte dos casos você não vai usar o XHTML.

Um exemplo de HTML4.01 com strict:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Olá mundo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Olá mundo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

E pra validar o seu HTML você pode usar este link https://validator.w3.org

Answer (score 3):

```html
<script>
    var imprime_1 = function(){
        document.writeln("Valor");
    }
    var imprime_2 = function(){
        var x = new String("var String");
        document.writeln(x);
    }
</script>
<form>
  <input type="button" value='ação1' onclick="imprime_1()">
  <input type="button" value='ação2' onclick="imprime_2()">
</form>
```

Comment: Não ta funcionando aq. Apareceu erro de sintaxe e nao conseguir descobri. olha o erro: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: @Jose.Lemo tente ver qual desses vai funcionar, de preferencia não copie o código para um arquivo, execute aqui mesmo

Comment: Infelizmente só da certo executando aqui, mas no meu arquivo nao dá, ..

Comment: tenta rodar no chrome, opera, pode ser que o seu browser esteja com problema, ou se vc estiver usando uma IDE online, pode ser esse o problema, evite usar IDEs online para fazer seus códigos, já vi muitos problemas que dão dor de cabeça.

Comment: Não dá certo Bruno. Mesmo vlw pela ajuda. Na verdade este comando está em desuso. mesmo erro: InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
 

document.writeln(x);

Answer (score 2):

Bem não sei qual o seu OS ou Navegador você esta usando pois testei no IE 11, FF *(atualizado)*, Chorme *(atualizado)*, Edge e Opera *(atualizados também)* no Windows 10 *(64 bits)* e todos funcionam, então acredito que o problema seja esse, seu Navegador e OS.

De qualquer forma o comando `document.writeln` não esta em desuso, nem nunca esteve pois até onde eu saiba não existe nenhum comando parecido a esse no JavaScript o mais proximo seria o `innerHTML` mas ele seria manipulação de elementos (DOM) e não escrita na tela, o que pode ocorrer é que PARECE segundo as documentações que existem incompatibilidade dessa tag com documentos XHTML como descrito aqui [W3C XHTML FAQ](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite), mas sinceramente nunca presenciei esse tipo de coisa.

Até porque a diferença do `document.writeln` para o `document.write` é minina a única coisa é que a primera dá quebra de linha como se fosse um "enter" ou também como um "\r\n" que na tradução fica:

```
\r = Carriage return 
\n = New line
```

E que pode váriar sua interpretação para cada OS que seria leia esse comando, pois dependendo da combinação pode adicionar ou faltar "enters":

- Mac: \r
- Linux/Unix: \n
- Windows: \r\n

O que está em desuso mas não obsoleto é iniciar o construtor como `new String("")`, que também são conhecidas como ["String objetos"](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) pois isso é mais comum no Java, no JavaScript ele é bem permicivo e fracamente tipado, então entro desuso sendo mais comum usar a ["String primitivas"](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), até porque existe muito pouca últilidade de ser fazer isso no JavaScript, ele serve mais para aramzenar uma cadeia de valores.

```
var var1 = "Texto 1";
var1.prop = "Texto 2";
alert(var1.prop); // undefined

var var1 = new String("Texto 1");
var1.prop = "Texto 2";
alert(var1.prop); // "Texto 2"
```

Comment: Estou usando a versao 45.0.1 (x86 pt-br), windows 8.1. Estou fazendo esses exemplo da XTI: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsLSPBQJ4R4&index=26&list=PLxQNfKs8YwvEk85FbeXxDnFecAntIQdRf

Answer (score 1):

O comando document.writeln(linha), não está em desuso, ele escreve uma linha onde o comando foi especificado, todo o xml pode ser sobrescrito se estiver fora fora das tags html.

Observe o código abaixo tirado do site http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_writeln.asp

Acesse para mais informações sobre document.writeln().

```
<body>

 <p>Note that write() does NOT add a new line after each statement:</p>

 <pre>
 <script>
  document.write("Hello World!");
  document.write("Have a nice day!");
 </script>
 </pre>

 <p>Note that writeln() add a new line after each statement:</p>

 <pre>
 <script>
  document.writeln("Hello World!");
  document.writeln("Have a nice day!");
 </script>
 </pre>

</body>
```