# writeln está obsoleto no JavaScript ou não?

Tags: javascript, java, html

tenho um exemplo de código simples

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>

var nome = "maria";
var sobrenome = "cardozo";
var nome2 = "pedro";
var sobrenome2 = "silva";

// Usando com write
document.write(nome);
document.write(sobrenome);

// Usando com writeln
document.writeln(nome2);
document.writeln(sobrenome2);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**NOTEM** que era para o `writeln` quebrar a linha. Mais não, ele funciona como se eu tivesse colocado como `write` para ficar apenas em uma linha esse método está obsoleto?

Comment: Dê uma olhada
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121598/document-writeln-est%C3%A1-em-desuso-javascript

Comment: Não, essa função não está em desuso, você pode conferi-la na documentação do mozilla firefox

Answer (score -1):

Eu adicionei a tag "pre" e funcionou.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<script>

var nome = "maria";
var sobrenome = "cardozo";
var nome2 = "pedro";
var sobrenome2 = "silva";

// Usando com write
document.write(nome);
document.write(sobrenome);

// Usando com writeln
document.writeln(nome2);
document.writeln(sobrenome2);

</script>
<pre>
</body>
</html>
```