# Como o navegador lida com laço infinito em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet, loop

Estava fazendo um exercício sobre laço de repetição `for` em Javascript no codecademy, porem, no exercício me deparei com o seguinte aviso:

> codecadeny
>
> Tenha muito cuidado com sua sintaxe — se você escrever um laço que não
>   possa finalizar corretamente, ele é chamado de laço infinito e irá
>   travar seu navegador!

E lá fui eu testar:

```js
for (var i = 2; i > 0; i++) {
 console.log(i);
}
```

**A responsabilidade de executar o código acima é sua, ele serve apenas como exemplo.**

E advinha o que aconteceu?
[image: Imagem ilustrativa]

Isso mesmo travou tudo :D

Entretanto, esta situação me deixou com algumas duvidas que são:

1. Como o navegador lida com o laço infinito?
2. Porque o travamento ocorre?
3. No ambiente de desenvolvimento WEB existe alguma forma ou ferramenta
   que minimize os efeitos causados pelo laço infinito?

Comment: Se tiver alguma sugestão de melhoria pode deixar um comentário.

Comment: Acho que ele lida quebrando a aba infratora :D Como ele detecta eu não sei, se é que faz. Em geral os navegadores possuem uma ferramenta que permite dar *pause*/colocar um *breakpoint* na execução, afinal o JS roda em um VM, com bastante controle se estiver em modo de desenvolvedor.

Comment: Estou aprendendo programação WEB e este efeito é mais devastador  do que em Desktop kkkk, eu acho que ele nem detecta, talvez alguma IDE alerte sobre isso, mais eu não sei.

Comment: talvez seja de interesse : [Como liberar thread congelado/travado?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100654/14213)

Comment: Aqui eu não deixei muito tempo, mas apesar de a página ficar travadona, foi só fechar no X da aba que tudo bem. O legal é que o Opera 12 lida melhor com isso (testei agorinha pra ter certeza) do que a versão atual, que usa o mesmo engine do Chrome. A atual trava. No 12 fica um pouco lento o browser, mas tudo funciona. Inclusive dou scroll na página com loop rodando, abro console, etc, o que indica basicamente isso como resposta: só depende da implementação de cada browser.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Existem vários cenários diferentes que podem travar seu navegador - sem contar os *bugs*. :P

## Execução demorada

A **execução demorada de um script** pode fazer ele ficar bloqueado, mas não necessariamente causar um travamento.

Exemplo:

```
for (var i = 2; i > 0; i++) {}
```

O código acima não faz a página travar e nem ocupa muito o processador, mas dado que a execução de JavaScript no navegador é realizada de forma síncrona, isto significa que o navegador fica impedido de realizar outras ações naquela página.

Se o navegador tiver alguma proteção contra isso, ele vai identificar que o script está demorando muito para retornar (*timeout*) e oferecer uma opção ao usuário para "matar" o processo daquela página ou aba. Caso contrário você terá que finalizar o navegador como um tudo.

## Consumo de memória

Entretanto, o código de exemplo da pergunta não apenas fica bloqueado num laço infinito, mas também **gera uma quantidade infinita de *output*** para o console.

A não ser que você tenha desativado o console, os dados vão sendo armazenados em algum local da memória até que não haja mais espaço disponível e aí você vai ter uma falha no processo. Se o console estiver sendo exibido na Ferramenta do Desenvolvedor, isso é pior ainda pois o navegador tem que atualizar a interface com o usuário, executando diversos cálculos de posicionamento dos textos, entre outras coisas.

Navegadores podem usar diferentes técnicas para prevenir um travamento total, como é o caso do Chrome, que usa um processo por página ou aba, o que significa que se uma aba travar, basta "matar" ela e a memória consumida será recuperada sem prejuízo ao sistema e às demais páginas ou abas.

Note que esta é apenas uma das muitas formas de consumir muita memória. Por exemplo:

- Vazamentos de memória podem ser introduzidos adicionando indefinidamente valores à objetos ou listas, ou mantendo referências a elementos que nem estão na página.
- Trabalhar com strings muito grandes, fazer concatenações em laços e coisas parecidas também podem acabar com a memória.
- Usar recursividade sem um limite adequado também vai travar o script.

## Evitando tais problemas

A verdade é que não existe uma forma prática e segura de evitar esse tipo de problema pois há muitas construções diferentes na linguagem que podem levar a tais situações.

Entretanto, as melhores abordagens que conheço são:

1. Escrever código modular ([AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html), [ES6](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#modules)) onde as funções e variáveis são isoladas tanto quanto possível.
2. Testar o seu código de forma automatizada e unitária ([QUnit](https://qunitjs.com/plugins/), [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html)).
3. Usar ferramentas de *linting* ([ESLint](http://eslint.org/)), isto é, que analisam seu código estaticamente, de acordo com regras pré-estabelecidas, procurando por práticas ruins e possíveis equívocos.
4. Use o paradigma funcional, quando possível

Especificamente sobre o item #3, ESLint possui uma lista de [regras](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/) definidas dentre as quais existem algumas que podem detectar laços sem condições de parada, como [esta](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unmodified-loop-condition). Se há algum erro frequente que não está ali, você pode escrever sua própria regra.

## Por que código modular

Algo importante é que, quanto mais confuso seu código, menos efetivo são os testes e a análise estática. Por isso o item #1 da minha lista acima está nessa posição.

Por exemplo, muita gente usa variáveis de escopo global em laços. O comportamento desse tipo de código é absurdamente complexo de prever.

```
function f1() {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) f2(); 
}
function f2() {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) whatever(); 
}
```

No exemplo acima, `f1` chama `f2` para cada execução do laço. Porém `i` não é uma variável local, então `f2` vai sempre terminar com `i = 5` e o laço em `f1` nunca vai acabar.

## Por que paradigma funcional

O **BrunoRB** mencionou algo muito importante acima, que é o uso de rotinas como `forEach` ao invés de fazer o laço manualmente.

O paradigma de programação funcional é conhecido por evitar vários problemas inerentes do paradigma imperativo, como este caso.

A ideia é usar rotinas especiais que encapsulam a lógica de percorrer determinada estrutura de dados, afinal elas são implementadas uma vez, testadas e tem pouquíssima chance de sofrer regressões. A partir diss você pode executar ações em cada elemento da estrutura de dados usando uma função *callback*.

Somente é importante considerar que, embora isso ajude a não errar com o contador de um laço, isso ainda não protege totalmente contra o mau uso de variáveis globais ou que são compartilhadas com outras funções, como no exemplo acima.

Answer (score 6):

Como 1 e 2 já foram bem respondidas nos comentários da questão e [na resposta do Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/126910/21328) vou apenas dar um adicional sobre a 3: é interessante você entender como detectar um loop infinito é um problema intratável chamado de [Halting Problem](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_da_parada), tanto para o browser quanto para alguma ferramenta de análise estática de código é impossível detectar laços infinitos (exceto em casos como `while(true);`, o que não é lá muito útil), o melhor que o browser consegue é verificar que seu código está executando a tempo demais sem pausa o que indica que tem algo errado, e aí ele pode tomar uma decisão sobre o que fazer, porém isso vai variar conforme o que quem implementou acha que é o melhor.

Sobres formas de evitar laços infinitos existem certas práticas de código que impossibilitam a ocorrência destes, um exemplo é que se ao invés de utilizar um `for(;;)` tradicional você sempre iterar sobre arrays com [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) ou [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), ou em objetos com `for...in` (`forEach` só funciona em arrays), fica impossível iterar infinitamente. Para os casos em que você não quer iterar sobre um objeto ou array, mas sim rodar certo trecho "N" vezes uma opção é criar um array com o tamanho igual ao número de iterações que você quer fazer e utilizar ele em conjunto com um foreach, exemplo:

```
// obs, fill só existe em chrome >=45 e firefox >=31
new Array(10).fill().forEach(function() {
   console.log('olá');
});
```

É meio exótico, principalmente porque javascript não possui uma maneira limpa de criar um array de tamanho X, a performance também vai sofrer (embora você precise criar uma quantidade realmente grande de laços de tamanho razoável para isso ser relevante), mas é uma técnica bacana para se conhecer (até porque que ela é a maneira padrão de se iterar em python e ruby e é tão limpa quanto um for padrão em php).

Answer (score 5):

> Como o navegador lida com o laço infinito?

Ele crasha. Acredita que o desenvolvedor sabe o que está a fazer e corre o código cegamente, bloqueando.

> Porque o travamento ocorre?

Porque usa a capacidade máxima de execução. O exemplo que tens na pergunta não dá espaço ao browser para respirar, ele vai tentar correr isso tão rápido quanto possivel, infinitas vezes. E como o processamento em JavaScript é *single threaded* ele só corre esse processo e o resto do código fica à espera que o loop acabe. Isso nunca acontece.

> No ambiente de desenvolvimento WEB existe alguma forma ou ferramenta que minimize os efeitos causados pelo laço infinito?

A única maneira é ter verificadores dentro do código que "procurem" por coisas irregulares. Algo assim:

```
for (var i = 2; i > 0; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    if (i > 100000) break;
}
```

Essa linha `if (i > 100000) break;` vai interromper o loop caso ele chegue à iteração cem mil.

Comment: um adendo, em computadores lentos ou OS que necessitam de uma formatação, esse tipo de ocorrência pode ocasionar o congelamento do navegador e manter o sistema ocupado por longos períodos de tempo