# Como escrever esse programa java usando o javascript e node?

Tags: javascript, java, thread

```
public class Principal {

private static int x = 0;
private static int y = 0;

public static void sum() {
    x = y + 1;
    y = x + 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

        Thread a = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                sum();
            }
        };
        a.start();

        Thread b = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                sum();
            }
        };
        b.start();

        System.out.println(x);
    }
  }
}
```

Como posso escrever esse algoritmo usando o node e javascript? Simplesmente não tenho a minima ideia de como fazer  isso! Estava analisando algumas formas e encontrei o `Web Worker` mas não consegui fazer nada.
O que devo fazer? Não sei como trabalhar com threads em node, tentei usar esse exemplo [node-threads-a-gogo](https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo) mas parece que ele não roda no windows.

Comment: Acho que isso deve ajudar a entender e simular algumas situações semelhantes a Thread em Javascript http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100657/3635, entenda que Javascript funciona somente com uma unica thread (apesar de eventualmente ser async), procure a parte escrita **Exemplo com web workers**

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como liberar thread congelado/travado?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100654/como-liberar-thread-congelado-travado)

Comment: @Guilherme , obrigado .Já havia lido esse exemplo ! Mas o problema é que eu ainda não tenho codigo algum em javascript!!!

Comment: Eu acho que não entendi, você não tem ou não sabe nada de javascript?

Comment: **Relacionado:** http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript não possui threads. Entretanto você pode executar métodos assíncronos. Exemplo a seguir:

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

function sum() {
  x = y + 1;
  y = x + 1;
}

function main() {

  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var a = setTimeout(function run(){ sum() }, 0);
    var b = setTimeout(function run(){ sum() }, 0);
  }

  console.log(x);

  // Complementar: Valor de X depois de 1 segundo.
  setTimeout(function(){ console.log(x); }, 1000);

}

main();
```

O resultado será:

> ```
> 0
> 39
> ```

Isso acontece porque os métodos assíncronos são declarados e preparados para execução - porém o scheduler não os invoca até depois do primeiro `console.log(x);`. A segunda chamada de console está lá para mostrar o resultado após um segundo.

Javascript possui [alguns métodos nativos que provém mecanismos assíncronos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9516967/1845714). Entre eles:

- setInterval
- setTimeout
- requestAnimationFrame
- XMLHttpRequest
- WebSocket
- Worker

Comment: Obrigado cara! Agora vou aprender um pouco sobre javascript começando em grande estilo!! Então para rodar o algoritmo acima eu posso fazer :  node  suarespostai.js ?

Comment: Só removeria os callbacks anomimos para chamar o sum direto :) ... +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu tentei deixar o mais parecido possível com o código original. Mas - boa dica, deixe-me ajustar... [*edit*] pronto. =)

Comment: @PenaPintada Sempre um prazer ajudar! Tente e me diga se funcionou. =)

Comment: @OnoSendai Do jeito anterior que você respondeu , também rodou  node sem problemas! Muito obrigado

Comment: Não acho que essa pergunta seja uma duplicata

Comment: @PenaPintada talvez não desta que linkei especifica, mas a pergunta de Threads em Js já foi feita sim, é que na resposta eu foquei o webworkers, que parecia ser sua necessidade inicial, de qualquer forma o problema foi mais você não conhecer nem o minimo da linguagem o que é um requisito no minimo basico para se fazer algo

Comment: @Entendi e concordo com você Guilherme , prometo que assim que acabar esse semestre aqui na faculdade vou me dedicar a fabulosa linguagem javascript para poder ajudar a turma por aqui, como vocês me ajudaram  !!