# Vida útil das threads no java

Tags: java, thread

Quando um objeto, de uma classe que implementa uma thread, for destruído (perde a referência) a thread referente a esse objeto irá parar?

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é uma Thread? Como ela funciona?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95233/28595)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação do Java em System.Threading.Thread:

> It is not necessary to retain a reference to a Thread object once you have started the thread. The thread continues to execute until the thread procedure is complete.

Ou seja, não é necessário manter uma referência para uma Thread após iniciá-la, a JVM gerencia a Thread e apenas encerra sua utilização quando run() for executado até seu fim.

Apesar disso é interessante manter a referência para fins de controle da Thread.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Excelente! Ajudou sim! Vou fazer outra pergunta, se não se importar: Mas se caso o objeto perder a referência o garbage collector limpará esse objeto da memória? E se ele limpar, como ficam os elementos utilizados pela thread (atributos da classe e métodos)???

Comment: É exatamente isso, o GC manterá a referência interna (e portanto estes objetos em memória) até que seja concluído o uso da thread. Feito isso tanto a thread quando os objetos usados por ela perdem "escopo" e são liberados da memória.

Comment: Faz bastante sentido. Vou procurar por essas documentações para mais detalhes. Mas você já esclareceu minhas dúvidas. Obrigado!