# Quando e por que devemos usar threads?

Tags: c#, .net, thread

Quando e por que devemos usar *threads*? Gostaria de alguns exemplos.

Comment: Tem algumas perguntas que podem ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123173/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131108/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14904/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95233/101 Uma delas deve, ou o conjunto responder isso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tenha em mente que todo programa já tem, pelo menos, uma *thread*, que é a *thread* principal (onde ele está rodando). Existem mil e um motivos para se usar *thread*, e cada programador deve saber qual a melhor ocasião, mas eu poderia listar alguns:

1. **Funções de longa duração:** por vezes, temos que invocar alguma função que demanda algum tempo pra ser executada. Se você não criar uma nova *thread*, esta função irá ser executada na *main thread,* ou *thread* principal, e vai parecer que seu programa parou de responder;
2. **Funções não prioritárias:** é possível definir a prioridade de cada *thread.* De repente, seu programa executa funções em segundo plano que não necessitam de grande prioridade, portanto, com o uso de uma nova *thread,* o usuário não perceberá impacto algum na utilização;
3. **Segurança:** caso algum erro e/ou *bug* aconteça na *thread* principal, seu programa irá travar; se acontecer em uma *thread* paralela, no máximo, uma mensagem de erro será exibida, permitindo que o usuário continue o que estava fazendo.

Answer (score 5):

Ao contrário da crença popular, que as respostas aqui presentes apresentam, *threads* servem para criar uma linha de processamento de uma aplicação com uma memória disponível para ela.

Ao contrário do [processo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131108/101) onde cada um tem sua própria memória, usando *thread* a memória é compartilhada entre as várias *threads* que estão no mesmo processo.

Quando um processo é iniciado sempre tem uma *thread* sendo iniciada junto. O que geralmente as pessoas querem saber é sobre criar novas *threads* no mesmo processo além da principal.

Então elas devem ser usadas quando precisa dessa linha de processamento extra no mesmo processo. Se pode ter uma linha de processamento com sua própria memória, então um novo processo é preferível na maioria dos casos, é mais fácil gerenciar isso (no passado isso não era totalmente verdade porque processo era muito caro e *thread* era mais barata, isso mudou). Pode ter exceção, mas precisa ser muito bem justificado.

E ao contrário do que foi dito, se você precisa apenas que o processo não fique travado em certa operação você pode usar tarefas ([`Task`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123173/101)) fazendo [assincronismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124283/101). Não importa se tem uma função de longa duração, ou que não seja prioritária, ou quer desempenho, até porque *thread* não dá desempenho. Quando apenas precisa de simultaneidade a *thread* pode resolver colateralmente, mas ela não é necessária.

Eventualmente uma *thread* pode dar algum benefício usando junto com uma `Task`, mas você não deveria se preocupar com isso na maioria das vezes.

A classe [`Thread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) raramente deveria ser usada de forma direta, mesmo quando precisa que mais de uma tarefa seja executada ao mesmo tempo, existem melhores abstrações para lidar com isso no .NET, começando pelas tarefas e a [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Curiosamente a resposta negativada acertou o que as outras erraram (provavelmente foi negativada por ser simples demais).

Geralmente a *thread* vai se beneficiar do computador com mais de um processador (*core*). Cada uma delas poderá rodar em cada um dos processadores de forma [paralela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166032/101). Não é possível uma mesma *thread* rodar em paralelo em processadores diferentes (é possível ela mudar de processador, mas não ter mais de uma linha ao mesmo tempo).

Frequentemente vemos a *thread* sendo usada sem necessidade de ser paralelo, e não está de todo errado, mas não é onde devemos, é apenas onde podemos usar *thread*.

O fato de rodar em mais de processador pode entregar o resultado em menor tempo total, mas isso não é o mesmo que dar mais desempenho. O seu uso pode, se usado adequadamente, usar melhor os recursos existentes. Se fizer errado pode ficar pior.

*Thread* não dá mais robustez ao código (um problema em uma *thread* afeta as outras, a não ser que o problema seja entrar em *loop* ou algo do tipo, mas aí chega a ser até problemático deixar algo rodando assim prejudicando toda aplicação, e de qualquer forma, se der algum ganho é de não bloquear, e não de segurança), por isso a ideia de segurança é errada.

Se compartilhar memória efetivamente é difícil fazer funcionar adequadamente e pode diminuir a robustez se a pessoa não souber bem o que está fazendo. Se não compartilhar ela tem pouca serventia.

Nem tudo pode ser quebrado em várias linhas de processamento. O que pode ser feito facilmente provavelmente deveria ser um novo processo. Quando uma parte depende de outro parte tende se tornar inviável quebrar.

Por exemplo somar todos os elementos de um *array* é fácil quebrar, no fim tudo dará certo se fizer a soma em 4 ou 8 ou mais linhas de processamento, desde que o *array* não seja alterado no meio do processo e cada um faça a sema em elementos bem definidos antes.

Achar a sequência de Fibonacci não pode ser quebrada, a não ser se usar algum truque porque você já sabe alguns resultados em certos pontos, mas aí pode ser que nem valha a pena gerar e ter ela pronta por completo, porque para saber o valor de um item da sequência depende do item anterior.

Fuja de *threads* se não souber muito bem o que está fazendo, é bem difícil até para pessoas experientes. Depurar por exemplo pode ser uma das maiores torturas que pode ter na vida, a não ser que esteja usando onde ela não é necessária.

Veja mais:

- [É sempre garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101)
- [O que são métodos Async?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175304/101)
- [Existem diferenças entre os termos Thread, Multithread, Async e Await?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208321/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre os async, multithreading, paralelismo e concorrência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157435/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Na prática quando uso Threads:

1. Quando não quero travar meu processamento principal, seja em em Forms ou em Web.
2. Quando preciso de desempenho e a operação não requer dependências de outras operações.

Em windows forms, praticamente não tem como não usar Multi-Thread, pois qualquer operação mais demorada trava a Thread principal, e para acessar os objetos de uma outra Thread, temos q usar delegates e o método invoke dos controls!

Um bom exemplo que usei Threads foi na importação de dados entre bancos diferentes, onde iríamos implantar um novo sistema em uma nova empresa e a empresa tinha um sistema legado, sem usar um sistema multi-thread a importação duraria cerca de 24h, usando Thread este tempo caiu consideravelmente para 35 minutos!

Answer (score -1):

Devemos usar threads todas as vezes que precisamos fazer duas tarefas ao mesmo tempo...

Se tiveres a necessidades de garregar duas Listas primeiro carregas e uma e depois carregas a outra.  Com thread podes carrega-las ao mesmo tempo.