# Paralelismo e Simultaneidade

Tags: paralelismo, concorrência, openmp

Lendo algumas coisas sobre o tema, percebi que não são a mesma coisa, por isso gostaria de descobrir:

- Qual a diferença entre **Paralelismo** e **Simultaneidade** em processos?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Paralelismo e Simultaneidade.

Muitas vezes a simultaneidade é chamada de [concorrência](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)) já que as tarefas concorrem entre si por uma unidade de execução, cada tarefa só pode executar por um punhado de tempo. Mas há quem defina a concorrência de outra forma.

Você só tem paralelismo quando pelo menos duas tarefas ocorrem simultaneamente. De verdade.

Note que o computador pode dar a impressão de [simultaneidade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneidade). De fato o termo simultaneidade é usado para a percepção, conforme o artigo da Wikipedia *linkado* acima descreve, mesmo que ele não seja específico para a computação. **A diferença é entre ser algo real ou apenas percepção**.

A percepção se dá com a troca entre tarefas. Cada tarefa é executada por um curto espaço de tempo e depois passa para outra tarefa. Como essas trocas ocorrem com tanta frequência (alguns poucos microssegundos) para um humano dá a impressão que as tarefas estão acontecendo ao mesmo tempo, mas só uma delas está executado de cada vez. Elas são simultâneas, mas não paralelas. A simultaneidade ajuda diminuir a latência.

O computador só pode obter paralelismo se tiver algum mecanismo que realmente rode mais de uma coisa ao mesmo tempo.

O mais comum é ter mais de um processador, físico ou lógico. Mesmo sendo lógico haverá um suporte físico que separe claramente as duas unidades de execução. Desta forma atinge-se um alto *throughput*.

O processador não precisa ser o principal, algumas tarefas são paralelizadas com processadores especializados.

Também é possível atingir paralelismo distribuído usando mais de um computador. Obviamente que dois computadores podem executar tarefas realmente ao mesmo tempo.

Qualquer aplicação rodando em um computador com um sistema operacional moderno e completo (excluindo algum nicho) pode executar em paralelo, ou pelo menos simultâneo. Na verdade é muito comum terem várias aplicações rodando ao mesmo tempo.

Duas tarefas podem ser paralelas sem serem concorrentes, elas podem ser totalmente independentes uma da outra. Pelo menos há uma definição que indica isso.

Pode ser observado no diagrama na [página da Wikipedia sobre o OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP).

[image: Paralelo X Concorrente]

Paralelismo puro não é difícil de alcançar. Se ele resolver seu problema é o melhor dos mundos. Mas sua forma pura só consegue ser usada em situações bem específicas. É difícil uma aplicação toda conseguir ser paralela por completa. Se as tarefas tiverem que se comunicar já começa complicar, se a comunicação for ao mesmo tempo que estão executando possivelmente já começamos ter concorrência pelos mesmos recursos.

A simultaneidade sem paralelismo só é útil em termos de percepção ou em casos onde há espera por recursos externos ao da unidade de execução. Como há um custo de administração, tornar algo simultâneo, mas não paralelo onde não há espera só deixa tudo mais lento. Como está se falando em percepção humana, o benefício ocorre assim mesmo já que o usuário não precisa ficar esperando por uma sequência de tarefas ir executando, mas demorará mais no todo.

A simultaneidade é muito útil em GUI, acesso à disco, rede, etc. Se ela puder executar paralelamente melhor ainda. Quando não há interação com usuários (nenhuma mesmo) ela pode ser bem menos útil se não tiver paralelismo.

Aplicações que almejam ser *real time* funcionam melhor se forem, seriais ou pelo menos puramente paralelas. Ainda é possível chegar perto do tempo real se a concorrência puder ser bem controlada, mas não 100% garantido.

## Concorrência

Há quem diga que a concorrência ocorre apenas quando essas tarefas são **dependentes** entre si. Existe concorrência quando elas concorrem por um recurso que ambas precisam acessar de alguma forma, além do processador. Pode ser memória, disco, etc. Nesse caso estamos falando de tarefas simultâneas que disputam quem pode acessar o que.

A concorrência, nesse contexto, pode ocorrer em tarefas paralelas ou só simultâneas.

A concorrência, nesse sentido, é um problema computacional difícil de resolver na maioria das situações. Existem formas para facilitar, mas se não souber o que está fazendo pode ter consequências catastróficas. E descobrir o que causa o problema quando algo dá erro é extremamente difícil. É um problema quase sempre não reproduzível sem ferramentas bem avançadas de diagnóstico e muita experiência. Quando programa-se concorrentemente vale mais ainda a afirmação de que tem que fazer **o certo**, não basta apenas funcionar. A ordem de execução não costuma ser determinística.

É muito difícil manter estados compartilhados de forma que não incorra em [*deadlocks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) ou [*livelocks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Livelock), mantenha a consistência e atomicidade.

## Serial

Para completeza, se tudo executar em uma linha única ela é chamada de serial. Muito raro hoje em dia, pelo menos na maioria dos dispositivos computacionais genéricos, mas não tão raro em dispositivos bem especializados.

## Conclusão

Tem tanta informação ambígua, desencontrada e até errada sobre o assunto que espero não ter sido eu mais um a ter escrito algo errado. Certamente terá quem ache errado ou certo de acordo com o que ela acredita ser o certo.

Já vi definições bastante aceitas que se opõe a essas duas linhas de pensamento.

[Leitura útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Você deve ter ficado em dúvida, pois a simultaneidade é mais "vista" nos livros como concorrência.

A simultaneidade pode ser vista como um estado operacional em que o computador "aparentemente" faz muitas coisas ao mesmo tempo. Já o paralelismo é a capacidade do computador fazer duas ou mais coisas as mesmo tempo.

A principal diferença entre paralelismo e simultaneidade é a velocidade de execução. Os programas concorrentes podem rodar centenas de caminhos de execução separados e não alteram a velocidade.

No  Livro: [Python eficaz: 59 maneiras de programar melhor em Python](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Python_eficaz.html?id=sU-iDAAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y) do autor Brett Slatkin, tem uma discussão sobre isso.

Comment: Resposta direta ao ponto sem 500 linhas pra explicar a diferença ao invés da enrolação das outras. Foi perguntado a diferença e não o significado das duas

Answer (score 0):

MULTIPROCESSAMENTO:
   Desde sua criação, os computadores têm sido vistos como máquinas seqüenciais, onde a UCP executa as instruções de um programa, uma de cada vez. Na realidade, essa visão não é totalmente verdadeira, pois, em nível de hardware, múltiplos sinais estão ativos simultaneamente, o que pode ser entendido como uma forma de paralelismo.

Com a implementação de sistemas com múltiplos processadores, o conceito de simultaneidade ou paralelismo pode ser expandido a um nível mais amplo, denominado multiprocessamento, onde uma tarefa pode ser dividida e executada, ao mesmo tempo por mais de um processador.

Paralelismo a nível de processador – A idéia é projetar computadores com mais de um processador que podem estar organizados de forma matricial, vetorial, compartilhando barramento com memória compartilhada ou não.

Tendo em vista que o conceito de paralelismo e simultaneidade são muito iguais, conclui-se que não há diferenças entre os mesmo, conforme menciona o pequeno trecho onde o autor retrata ao dizer paralelismo ou simultaneidade.