# Execução de programas em pararelo SEM uso de Threads

Tags: java, linux, thread, processo

Pedem-me para elaborar um programa Java, que execute programas (`ls`, `firefox`) em paralelo que estão contidos num ficheiro.

Para já tenho o seguinte código:

```
     File file = new File()`;

     List<String> lista = file.readFile(args[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) { //percorre o ciclo de comandos que são enviados como argumentos no terminal
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(lista.get(i)); //criacao de processos externos à JVM (Java Virtual Machine)
            Process process = pb.start();

            System.out.println("Inicio do comando \"" + lista.get(i) + "\".");
            InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(isr);

            String line;

            while((line = bf.readLine())!= null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            System.out.println("Fim do comando \"" +args[i] + "\".");
```

`args[0]` faz referência ao nome do ficheiro que passo por linha de comandos. A minha dúvida era:

- como sei que realmente os processos estão a ser executados em paralelo?

A minha lógica era:

- usar como podem ver no código acima a impressão para o ecrã do inicio
  e o fim do programa. O meu *output* dá o seguinte:

> zeluis@zeluis-HP-EliteBook-8460p ~/NetBeansProjects/SOCP2/src/socp2 $ java -cp .. socp2.Shell ficheiroSO2.txt

```
Isto é um programa que processa em paralelo os seus processos
Inicio do comando "ls".
ficheiroSO2.txt
File.class
File.java
Shell.class
Shell.java
Fim do comando "ficheiroSO2.txt".
Inicio do comando "firefox"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> como sei que realmente os processos estão a ser executados em paralelo?

Simples, se você tem mais de um processador, e hoje é comum ter pelo menos 4, eles estão rodando em paralelo. Se só tem um processador eles não estão rodando em paralelo. O sistema operacional cuida disto.

Mesmo que não esteja rodando em paralelo estarão rodando concorrentemente já que o sistema operacional também cuida disto.

Você essencialmente não tem muito controle sobre como a execução dos processos ocorrerá.

Você não poderia executar outros programas dentro de *threads*, elas só existem dentro de um processo.

Coisas para ler e entender melhor:

- [Existe diferença entre Programa, Thread e Processo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131108/101)
- [Paralelismo e Simultaneidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166032/101)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou ler melhor!

Answer (score 4):

A grosso modo, se você quer algo MIMD, precisa usar cabeças de processamento separaras. Os modos tradicionais disso são:

1. Threads
2. Processos
3. Programa distribuído

Em ambientes Unix, você cria processos novos a partir do `fork`. Mas esse processo novo é uma cópia da imagem do processo anterior. Inclusive, na ao chamar em C o `fork`, tanto o processo novo quanto a cópia vão se situar exatamente na mesma linha, a linha logo após a chamada dessa método.

Para substituir a imagem, você tem a chamada da família `exec`. Como `execve`, se não me engano. Essa chamada fará a substituição da imagem do processo anterior pela do processo novo.

Então, se você estiver rodando o programa A, e então chama o programa B, duas coisas podem acontecer:

1. o programa A é totalmente substituído pelo programa B; não tem salvação para A, até mesmo as threads serão sobrescritas; isso acontece quando você não chama o `fork` antes do `exec`
2. o programa A é clonado e então esse clone é substituído pelo programa B; isso acontece quando você chama o `fork` antes da criação do programa B

No seu caso, você está em Java. Ele esconde essa feiúra toda do SO para você se preocupar com suas coisas. Se você viu o `firefox` ou o `ls` sendo executados, então com certeza houve uma chamada para substituir a imagem do programa Java com a imagem do programa novo; ou seja, teve um `exec`. Você também percebeu que seu programa não parou a execução, o que indica que houve antes da sobrescrita da imagem do executável, um `fork`. O Java por si só faz isso para você não precisar se preocupar com nenhum detalhe.

Quando você manda o processo iniciar através do `processBuilder.start()`, ele já nasce como um processo diferente do seu e rodará, paralelo ao seu programa (se não concorrer por CPU ou outro recurso de máquina, como reparado pelo @Maniero em sua resposta). Se você quiser esperar o processo criado parar, você precisa chamar `process.waitFor()`, ou então simplesmente `processBuilder.start().waitFor()`, neste caso em específico você tem certeza que os programas não estão em paralelo não concorrente.