# Por que variáveis de uma mesma instância não pode ser lida em processos diferentes? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes

Tenho dois processos acontecendo e tenho uma classe contendo um método que modifica um valor, como podem ver no código abaixo. A função EventoBotão representa um clique, para modificar um valor. Mas a questão é, por que só ocorre a mudança dentro da funcao1 e não da funcao2, ou o contrário se chamar a função EventoBotão dentro da funcao2?
Se as duas usam a mesma instância da classe, se o valor da variável é modificado, não deveria ser impresso o valor 100 nas duas chamadas para mostrar o valor? Se alguém puder explicar o porque isso não acontece e qual seria a forma para "acessar" o valor da variável nos dois processos.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue



class Aplicativo(object):

    Comando = 0

    def MostraValor(self):

        print("VALOR CMD = ", self.__class__.Comando)

    def InsereValores(self, Cmd):

        self.__class__.Comando = Cmd

    def EventoBotao(self):
        self.InsereValores(100)

App = Aplicativo()


def Funcao1():
    App.EventoBotao()
    App.MostraValor()



def Funcao2():

    App.MostraValor()


if __name__ == "__main__":


    p1 = Process(target=Funcao1)
    p2 = Process(target=Funcao2)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não está realmente acessando a mesma instância. Quando você cria processos diferentes, todo o estado do programa é duplicado em memória e cada processo só modifica a instância na memória que o pertence.

Não é muito recomendável usar a mesma memória para processos separados. O ideal é usar um Pipe ou Queue:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def escrever_numeros(conn):
    for i in range(10):
        conn.send(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn1, conn2 = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=escrever_numeros, args=(conn2,))
    p.start()

    while True:
        print('Recebi do outro processo:', conn1.recv())
```

Caso realmente necessário, você pode usar [`Value` e `Array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

Como recomendações pro seu código:

- Não use `__class__`; você não está editando as variáveis da instância, mas sim da *classe* quando faz isso. Pra modificar as variáveis da instância, as inicie num construtor `__init__` e use `self.variavel`:

  ```
  class Aplicativo(object):

      def __init__(self):
          self.comando = 0

      def insere_valores(self, cmd):
          self.comando = cmd

      ...
  ```
- Procure usar as [convenções de estilo do Python](https://wiki.python.org.br/GuiaDeEstilo). O nome de suas variáveis, por exemplo, deve ser em letras minúsculas e separadas por `_`.
- Pra uma aplicação com a estrutura do seu exemplo, é improvável que você realmente tenha que usar multiprocessing. Considere fazer sem.

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta! Na verdade tenho uma comunicação serial em um processo e interface gráfica executando em outra. Por isso resumi para fazer a pergunta. Já usei  o queue e tudo mais, mas estava me parecendo insuficiente para minhas necessidades. Por isso queria modificar e ler a variável da "mesma" instância.

Comment: @FilipeSantos modificar variáveis da mesma instância em processos diferentes não é recomendável por causa de problemas de sincronização; os dois processos podem escrever ao mesmo tempo e isso acaba causando mais dor de cabeça do que repensar a estrutura do programa pra poder usar uma Queue ou Pipe adequadamente. Se quiser tentar, veja a documentação que linkei pra `Value` e `Array`, mas o que eu recomendaria é investir mais tempo na Queue mesmo.

Comment: Boa resposta. Acho que vale a pena referênciar que assim: https://repl.it/repls/InfamousGraveAmurstarfish pode solucionar o problema,  pois o objeto sobre os quais os processos vão trabalhar já vai com os valores internos modificados. Estes só se tornam 'independentes' após cada processo ficar com uma 'cópia' do obj, que neste caso já vai com o valor `100`

Answer (score 1):

Tudo isso é devido ao modelo de paralelismo usado.

[Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/257047/64969) falei sobre Java, mas a base se aplica a maioria dos sistemas operacionais modernos. Quando você manda fazer um processo novo, você está fazendo um programa novo (através da chamada `fork` ao SO). Assim, você terá processos separados.

> [Existe diferença entre Programa, Thread e Processo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131108/64969)

Como visto na resposta linkada, processos separados tem áreas de memória separadas. Então, a não ser que você crie uma [IPC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211430/64969), um processo não conseguirá ler a variável do outro processo.