# Utilizar um ThreadPool ou apenas inicializar uma nova Thread?

Tags: java, thread, concorrência

Digamos que o software toda a vez cria um `new Runnable` para realizar uma função básica a cada ciclo, ao final de um dia de execução eu teria algumas centenas de Threads desta função criadas e finalizadas corretamente pela JVM.

Quais vantagens e desvantagens eu encotraria em **reutilizar** uma thread com, por exemplo, o `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n)`, comparado por **toda vez criar** um `new Runnable` quando precisar executar?

O que eu ganharia reutilizando as Threads ou então o que eu não ganharia  reutilizando as Threads?

Comment: Mais leitura sobre Threads [O que é uma Thread? Como ela funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95233/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-thread-como-ela-funciona?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A alocação de Threads é uma questão um tanto quanto custosa.

Instanciar uma thread nova requer uma chamada o sistema operacional e uma alocação de memória (cada thread possui sua própria pilha). Além de, se você sem querer criar threads demais, você pode sufocar a CPU com isso.

Trocar de uma thread para outra também é um processo um tanto caro para o processador, cada thread possui contexto próprio, e trocar o contexto é um problema. Portanto, quando você sai da sua Thread principal para criar a nova Thread, isso pode ser um problema.

Em um diagrama bem simplificado, funciona da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O custo de troca dessas trocas todas de contexto é muito alto,** e acontecerá toda vez que você inicializar uma Thread.

Quando você usa uma ThreadPool para executar suas tarefas, todas as Threads já foram alocadas. Portanto, esse custo já foi pago, uma única vez. As threads alocadas então buscam numa fila quaisquer tarefas a serem executadas (Por exemplo o seu Runnable).

Manter uma ThreadPool tende a ser menos custoso do que instanciar Threads novas toda vez que você executar uma ação.

**No entanto:**

Se as ações que você executa são muito esporádicas (duas vezes por dia, por exemplo), pode ser mais eficiente alocar uma Thread nova somente quando a ação for executada.

As ThreadPools são mais usadas para executar ações que acontecem rotineiramente (por exemplo servir páginas Web para um cliente. Isso acontece toda vez que um cliente acessa a página, logo acontece várias vezes)

---

### Resumindo:

Criar novas Threads é muito caro. Ao utilizar uma ThreadPool, você reduz consideravelmente esse custo, tornando sua aplicação mais performática, além de evitar problemas de concorrência por uma má implementação

Comment: Obrigado Kerooker! Então por eu ter a Thread já alocada na minha JVM, toda essa troca de contexto não acontece? E deixar esse espaço para o Pool de Thread reservado, não é igualmente ruim por esta lá alocado sem nenhuma funcionalidade?

Comment: Não. O custo para você manter uma threadpool (mesmo que seja de uma thread, por exemplo) tende a ser mais barato do que alocar uma thread nova toda vez

Comment: No entanto, se a ação que você for fazer seja completamente esporática (duas vezes por dia, por exemplo) pode compensar alocar uma thread nova toda vez.

Comment: Editando a resposta para incluir esses fatores