# Como funciona a sincronização em Java?

Tags: java, thread, lock

Qual é a vantagem de ter duas *threads*, que rodam ao mesmo tempo mas que uma espera a outra ser concluída para ser executada? Quando se utiliza a palavra chave SYNCHRONIZED em uma aplicação JAVA com THREADS, fica estabelecido que uma thread só pode ser executada após o final da outra. Neste caso, qual a vantagem de se utilizar a thread em lugar de uma aplicação mono-tarefa?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95233/o-que-%c3%a9-uma-thread-como-ela-funciona, creio que essa pergunta possui a resposta que tu deseja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De fato se isto acontecer não deveria usar desta forma.

As pessoas tem a crença de que colocando novas *threads* tudo fica rápido, mas frequentemente fica mais lento. Veja [É sempre garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101).

Se a *thread* ficar travada esperando outra na maior parte do tempo então só haverá perda de tempo, nunca ganho. Se esta espera é eventual pode ainda ter algum ganho, ainda que não seja tão grande, por isso tem que pensar bem se vale a pena a complexidade de fazer isto, até porque ambiente *multithread* é mais difícil de programar e muita coisa pode dar errada.

Só há este problema se pelo menos duas *threads* competem pelo mesmo recurso durante o processamento. Sem *threads* neste cenário a competição não existirá mas a velocidade seria limitada. Quando você coloca outra *thread* pode diminuir bem o tempo para finalizar enquanto elas não estão competindo pelo recurso e a espera só acontece em alguns momentos, se acontecer de fato. Em muitos casos o travamento de uma *thread* é muito curto então a espera não é longa. Não quer dizer que isto é bom, mas se é eventual não é um grande problema.

Onde se espera competição real em muitos casos não vale a pena usar este tipo de estratégia. Existem estruturas de dados que não precisam de sincronização e permitem melhor competição. Claro que elas possuem outras desvantagens, então não pode ser usado em qualquer caso. E a maioria das situações a solução é ter um processamento serializado mesmo.

Pensa em um banco de dados. Muitos funcionam assim, ele trava o registro que está trabalhando porque é improvável que outra operação esteja acessando o mesmo dado, mas se isto acontecer então haverá uma espera e isso não é bom, mas é melhor que essa operação acessar o dado que já está sendo acessando. Alguns bancos de dados usam um sistema chamado MVCC em que tudo o que for alterado é copiado então o acesso não cria problemas.

Se os acessos serão só de leitura a sincronização não é necessária.

Answer (score 1):

Não entendo como duplicada porque a pergunta é mais especifica do que "o que é thread", bom a resposta é relativamente simples, essa situação que você apresentou o maior motivo é que "se paga pelo processamento mais lento"

Suponhamos

Uma execução em thread onde a primeira contem um código que demora em média 1 segundo para ser executado e na segunda thread contem um código que demora 3 segundos, caso fosse executado os processos de forma sequencial a demora seria de um total de 4 segundo, mas executando em paralelo a execução mais rápida paga o preço da mais lenta sendo assim os valores não se somam e apenas o mais lento é levado em consideração.

Obviamente existe uma perda de performance na quebra em threads deveria ser observado caso a caso a necessidade, mas basicamente a logica é essa, a de pagar apenas pelo processamento mais lento.