# Barra de progresso só aparece quando o download termina

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Galera é o seguinte, eu estava fazendo uma barra de progresso para um download de um arquivo na web, mas não funciona. Quando executo o código, a janela do tkinter fica travada e só retorna quando o download termina. Alguém sabe em que estou errando? Já estou há 2 dias nesse problema. Segue a parte do código abaixo:

```
def read_bytes(self):
with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
    response = requests.get(linkd, stream=True)
    total_length = response.headers.get('content-length')
    if total_length is None:
        f.write(response.content)
    else:
        dl = 0
        total_length = int(total_length)
        for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
            dl += len(data)
            f.write(data)
            self.bytes = dl
            self.progress["value"] = self.bytes
            if self.bytes < self.maxbytes:
                self.after(100)
            elif self.bytes >= self.maxbytes:
                self.exit = ttk.Label(self, text="Terminado",
                                       background = 'black',
                                       foreground = 'white')
                                       self.exit.pack()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema não é a barra de progresso que trava o programa, mas sim o código de download. A interface gráfica do `tkinter` roda sempre na *main thread* e mais nenhum código pode rodar nela a partir do momento que você executa o `mainloop` ou sua interface poderá travar.

Um bom exemplo disso é a função `time.sleep` que faz o programa dormir e trava a interface:

```
def btn_function():
    time.sleep(2)

root = Tk()
Button(root, text = "Aguardar 2 segundos", command = btn_function).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

No exemplo acima, o programador que criou o código pensava que poderia fazer o programa apenas aguardar com o `time.sleep` sem travar a interface, mas isso não ocorre pois a função é chamada na thread principal.

*"Mas o meu código não pede para o programa dormir, ele só faz download de um arquivo."*

Realmente, mas existe uma espera até que o download seja feito, sendo justamente essa espera que afeta a interface e faz ela travar por um tempo.

A solução para isso é criar uma [`Thread`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95233/157404), para que a execução do seu download não afete a execução da interface gráfica.

Veja este exemplo:

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
import requests

def download():
    response = requests.get("<url>")
    with open('page.html','wb') as file:
        file.write(response.content)

def btn_function():
    print("Downloading...")
    Thread(target = download).start()

root = Tk()
Button(root, text = "Download", command = btn_function).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Obrigado mano! Adaptei meu código com esse conceito que você apresentou e aparentemente deu certo, ótima explicação. Assunto resolvido :)