# Sou iniciante em java e estou buscando conhecer mais sobre, e por isso gostaria de saber como que faço pra saber se as threads estão rodando?

Tags: java

```
import com.sun.corba.se.spi.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPool;



public class Game {
private boolean isAlive;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length !=2){
        System.out.println("teste de thread");
        System.out.println("testando");
    }
    
    int numTasks = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    
   
    ThreadPool threadPool = new ThreadPool(numThreads);
    
   
    for(int i =0; i<numTasks; i++){
        threadPool.runTask(createTask(i));
    }
}
    private static Runnable createTask(final int taskID){
        return new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                System.out.println("task "+taskID+": start");
                try{
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }catch(InterruptedException rx){}
                System.out.println("task "+taskID+": end");
            }
        
        }
    
    }
```

}

Comment: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1323408) tem algumas opções (não testei). Mas no seu caso, não é só ver se as mensagens "task start" e "task end" estão aparecendo?

Comment: Nesse caso a mensagem "task end" nunca vai aparecer porque as threads não são interrompidas. Interromper uma thread é uma ação que precisa ser feita explicitamente e não tem nada a ver com o término normal da thread.

Answer (score 0):

A classe `Thread` é uma abstração do Java para threads do sistema operacional.

A classe tipicamente usada para criar um pool de threads está errada. Não seria `ThreadPool` do pacote do CORBA, e sim por exemplo um `Executor` do pacote de concorrência do Java.

Mesmo assim ele não dará acesso às threads individuais do pool (tanque) de threads e sim a uma API para agendamento de tarefas a serem executadas pelas threads desse pool, de maneira fechada, sem controle das threads individuais.

Para saber se uma thread específica está rodando uma forma é instanciá-la e guardar sua referência em uma variável. Exemplo:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
thread.start();

if (thread.isAlive()) {
    System.out.println("A thread está rodando.");
}
```

Para entender mais sobre threads estude material sobre `Thread`s do Java (no *[Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)* da Oracle tem, em inglês), os recursos de controle de concorrência, e posteriormente sobre os `Executors` para criar pools de threads.

Vale a pena também estudar sobre threads do ponto de vista do sistema operacional. Um possível ponto inicial: [O que é uma Thread? Como ela funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95233/357)

Comment: vlw Piovezan!!!

Comment: Faça o [tour] para saber como agradecer.